# MS SQL Server Enterprise 2016 is truncating the audited select statements, how do we fix it?

Tags: sql-server-2016, functions, view, audit, database-link

## TL;DR;

I am getting `SELECT` as the audit output instead of the actual (suspected) query `SELECT DISTINCT CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByPassphrase(getkey(N'key1'), FIELD1)) as DECRYPTED_FIELD1 FROM view1 WHERE RECORD_ID = $id`. Other queries audit just fine. Why and how do we fix it?

## The Suspected Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    CONVERT(varchar, DecryptByPassphrase(getkey(N'key1'), FIELD1)) as DECRYPTED_FIELD1
FROM view1
WHERE RECORD_ID = $id;
```

It may or may not be using prepared statements with a bind variable for the `$id`. We have confirmed the connection is via JDBC.

Another query, that audits fine is:

```
update view1 
set FIELD2 = $v1
where FIELD3 = $v2;
```

## Actual Audit Records

They are as follows:

| event_time | server_principal_name | statement | object_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7901604 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | view1 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7910692 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table14 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7910692 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | view4 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7920464 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table17 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7920464 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table16 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7929764 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table15 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7929764 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | view3 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7929764 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table13 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7939486 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table12 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7939486 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table11 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7939486 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table10 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7949390 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table9 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7949390 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | view2 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7949390 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table8 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7959682 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table8 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7959682 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table7 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7968892 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table7 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7968892 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table6 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7978771 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | otherdb.table5 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7978771 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table4 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7988691 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table3 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7988691 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table2 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.7988691 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT | table1 |
| 2021-03-02 17:21:03.8017734 | DOMAIN\username | SELECT @v_key_value = k.key FROM keystable k WHERE k.name = @p_key_name | keystable |
| 2021-01-15 17:08:00.9462817 | DOMAIN\username | update view1 set FIELD2 = @P0 where FIELD3 = @P1 | ... |

### Areas of research

Here are some of the relevant areas of research that have proven to not be the issue.

#### SQL Statement too long?

This should not be an issue, because [sys.fn_get_audit_file_transact_sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-get-audit-file-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) will wap the query and increment `sequence_number` . See [dzone.com article on sql-audit-not-showing-full-sql-statement](https://dzone.com/articles/sql-audit-not-showing-full-sql-statement) for an example.

#### SQL Statement redacted?

This does not appear to be an issue either. Certain items, e.g. password changes, are redacted when logged in an audit. They are redacted with a series of `*` marks. See [sqlservercentral.com article on auditing password changes](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/auditing-the-password-changes-using-login_change_password_group-server).

### Audit definition

```
USE [master];
GO

CREATE SERVER AUDIT [AuditSELECT_123456789]
TO FILE 
(   FILEPATH = N'x:\Audits\'
    ,MAXSIZE = 20 MB
    ,MAX_ROLLOVER_FILES = 2147483647
    ,RESERVE_DISK_SPACE = OFF
)
WITH
(   QUEUE_DELAY = 1000
    ,ON_FAILURE = CONTINUE
    ,AUDIT_GUID = 'd985d743-efb5-466f-be47-901b6a572753'
)
ALTER SERVER AUDIT [AuditSELECT_123456789] WITH (STATE = ON);
GO

Use [DATABASENAME];
GO


CREATE DATABASE AUDIT SPECIFICATION [AuditSELECT_123456789]
FOR SERVER AUDIT [AuditSELECT_123456789]
ADD (DELETE ON DATABASE::[DATABASENAME] BY [USERNAME]),
ADD (EXECUTE ON DATABASE::[DATABASENAME] BY [USERNAME]),
ADD (INSERT ON DATABASE::[DATABASENAME] BY [USERNAME]),
ADD (RECEIVE ON DATABASE::[DATABASENAME] BY [USERNAME]),
ADD (SELECT ON DATABASE::[DATABASENAME] BY [USERNAME]),
ADD (UPDATE ON DATABASE::[DATABASENAME] BY [USERNAME])
WITH (STATE = ON);
```

## Server info

Windows 2012r2 64 bit, SQL Server version 13.0.5865.1 Enterprise 64 bit, otherwise current on patches.

## UDF and View psuedo code source

### getkey udf

It executes as the caller

```
CREATE FUNCTION getkey(@p_key_name NVARCHAR(128))
RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
WITH RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @v_key_value VARCHAR(1024);
SELECT @v_key_value = k.key FROM keystable k WHERE k.name = @p_key_name;
RETURN @v_key_value;
END;
```

### view1

```
select * 
FROM table1 
JOIN table2 
JOIN table3 
JOIN table4 
JOIN otherdb.table5 
JOIN table2 
JOIN table1 
JOIN table6 
JOIN view2 
JOIN table9 
JOIN table9 
JOIN table10 
JOIN table11 
JOIN view3 
JOIN view4 
JOIN table14
```

### view2

```
SELECT * 
FROM table7 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM table8
```

### view3

```
select * 
FROM table12 
JOIN table7 
JOIN table7 
JOIN table13 
JOIN table7 
JOIN table8
```

### view4

```
select * 
FROM table15 
JOIN table16 
JOIN table17
```

Comment: I seem to recall that you can track in audit password changes, but not see the passwords themselves. Which makes sense from security point of view. Maybe your case is similar? Your query contains passphrase. I think it could also be considered security sensitive data.

Comment: Looked in to that line of reasoning, here we are missing significant portions of the select statement body, not just literals and variables. It is almost like there is a carriage return after the SELECT and it is only showing line 1.